# C# - binding datatable to reportviewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I'm trying to bind a `DataTable` to a `reportviewer` in `winforms` at runtime but I get this message in the `reportviewer` (not an exception)"

The source of the report definition has not been specified"

Here's my code:

```
this.rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); 

ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt); 

this.rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource); 
this.rptViewer.RefreshReport();
```

any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var reportDataSource1 = new ReportDataSource { Name = "WpfApplication17_User", Value = _users };
string exeFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
_reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath =exeFolder + @"\Reports\Report1.rdlc";
_reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
_reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Got the answer from [here (Codeproject)](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/477074/Theplussourceplusofplustheplusreportplusdefinition).

Comment: what is inputValuesTableAdapter.GetData()?

Comment: @FabianBigler He's got 4 questions with 0 accepted, good luck on that :P. +1 for the investigative work.

Comment: @KreepN Yeah that's why I tried to remember him :D Thanks, mate!